# dplyr: colSums on sub-grouped (group_by) data frames: elegantly

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a very large dataframe (265,874 x 30), with three sensible groups: an age category (1-6), dates (5479 such) and geographic locality (4 total). Each record consists of a choice from each of these, plus 27 count variables. I want to group by each of the grouping variables, then take a colSums on the resulting sub-grouped 27 variables. I've been trying to use **dplyr** (v0.2) to do it, because doing it manually ends up setting up a lot of redundant things (or resorting to a loop for iterating across the grouping options, for lack of an elegant solution).

**Example code**:

```
countData <- sample(0:10, 2000, replace = TRUE)
dates <- sample(seq(as.Date("2010/1/1"), as.Date("2010/01/30"), "days"), 200, replace = TRUE)
locality <- sample(1:2, 2000, replace = TRUE)
ageCat <- sample(1:2, 2000, replace = TRUE)
sampleDF <- data.frame(dates, locality, ageCat, matrix(countData, nrow = 200, ncol = 10))
```

then what I'd like to do is ...

```
library("dplyr")
sampleDF %.% group_by(locality, ageCat, dates) %.% do(colSums(.[, -(1:3)]))
```

but this doesn't quite work, as the results from colSums() aren't data frames. If I cast it, it works:

```
sampleDF %.% group_by(locality, ageCat, dates) %.% do(data.frame(matrix(colSums(.[, -(1:3)]), nrow = 1, ncol = 10)))
```

but the final do(...) bit seems very clunky.

Any thoughts on how to do this more elegantly or effectively? I guess the question comes down to: how best to use the do() function and the . operator to summarize a data frame via colSums.

Note: the do(.) operator only applies to **dplyr** 0.2, so you need to grab it from GitHub ([link](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr)), not from CRAN.

*Edit: results from suggestions*

**Three solutions**:

1. My suggestion in post: elapsed, 146.765 seconds.
2. @joran's suggestion below: 6.902 seconds
3. @eddi's suggestion in the comments, using data.table: 6.715 seconds.

I didn't bother to replicate, just used system.time() to get a rough gauge. From the looks of it, **dplyr** and **data.table** perform approximately the same on my data set, and both are significantly faster when used properly than the hack solution I came up with yesterday.

Comment: Would you mind sharing a link to where exactly dplyr 0.2 can be downloaded? I would appreciate that since I didnt find the download on GitHub (and it might make it easier for other community members to answer your question).

Comment: @beginneR If you look through the ReadMe file on the github page, you'll see the command for installing from github. (Using the devtools package).

Comment: @joran awesome, now installing.. thanks for that hint.

Comment: @beginneR I had a little trouble with the **magrittr** dependency on OS X, which I had to install from source; it was looking for the wrong version of the binary for some reason.

Comment: @joran it seems to work fine (i just tested the code from your answer which shouldnt be possible with dplyr 0.1.3 according to my understanding). However, in the packages view in RStudio it still shows version 0.1.3.

Comment: since your question is specifically about `dplyr` I'm putting this as a comment - here's less clunky (and likely faster) syntax: `dt = as.data.table(sampleDF)`; `dt[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = list(locality, ageCat, dates)]`

Comment: @eddi I must be timing it wrong, then, because the dplyr version is running ~2x faster for me on the OP's data using microbenchmark. I would have expected that they'd be pretty even. Perhaps if we ramped up the size (or the number of groups) considerably that would change?

Comment: joran, likely due to groups (and the effect of `as.data.table` being bigger than the operation itself). [This gist](https://gist.github.com/arunsrinivasan/db6e1ce05227f120a2c9) might give some idea.

Comment: @eddi: thanks for the great suggestion. Equally fast vs. dplyr's summarise_each, and nice and concise.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, this seems like a job for `summarise_each` (a sort of `colwise` analogue from **plyr**):

```
sampleDF %.% group_by(locality, ageCat, dates) %.% summarise_each(funs(sum))
```

The grouping column are not included in the summarizing function by default, and you can select only a subset of columns to apply the functions to using the same technique as when using `select`.

(`summarise_each` is in version 0.2 of **dplyr** but not in 0.1.3, as far as I know.)

Comment: I had missed summarise_each: thanks for the suggestion! It's significantly faster than casting repeatedly, as the edit to my original post shows.

Answer (score 6):

The method `summarise_each` mentioned in [joran's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23768654) from 2014 has been deprecated.

Instead, please use `summarize_all()` or `summarize_at()`.

Answer (score 3):

The methods `summarize_all` and `summarize_at` mentioned in [Hack-R's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51468363) from 2018 have been superseded.

Instead, please use `summarize()`/`summarise()` combined with `across()`.