# R - Averaging large matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I currently have a large matrix, with **72 rows** and **919 columns**.

```
amatrix <- matrix(rexp(919, rate=.1), ncol=919, nrow=72)
```

As this is a data frame containing [technical replicates](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=12&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwia5OGmrbPcAhVCGt8KHW02AREQFgheMAs&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.nigms.nih.gov%2Ftraining%2Fdocuments%2Fmodule3-biological-and-technical-replicates.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0So5eBDfj9opr1G4Z8tkUV), I must first average the values for the technical replicates, prior to further analysis. The technical replicates are sequential (rows), in groups of 3.

- Is there a way to average 3 rows at a time together, to result in a new matrix with **24 rows** and **919 columns**?

I have been doing this part manually so far and importing the data back into R. There must be a way to do this in R, but I can't find a similar answer.

Comment: This is confusing because it can't be both a matrix and a data frame. Please make it clear why you refer to it as a data frame since that actually has some impact on calculation.

Comment: `rowsum` is a funky (and fast) wee function for this sort of thing...`rowsum(amatrix, rep(1:(72/3), each=3))/3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the key thing is to know how to describe the pattern using R code, e.g.

```
rep(1:(nrow(amatrix)/3), each=3)
```

Then it's simply a matter of group-level aggregation. You can do this with any base, `dplyr`, `data.table`, or other aggregation method.

Let's start with base R.

I prefer to work with this as a `data.frame`, but you could also keep it as a matrix and just use `[]` indexing instead of `$` to create a new vector:

```
amatrix                      <- as.data.frame(matrix(rexp(919, rate=.1), ncol=919, nrow=72))
amatrix$technical_rep_number <- rep(1:(nrow(amatrix)/3), each=3)
```

Creation of this vector is actually entirely optional. You could also leave your matrix as-is and just specify the pattern (`rep(1:(nrow(amatrix)/3), each=3)`, in this case) within the aggregation function.

From base R we can use `aggregate`:

```
new_table <- aggregate(amatrix, by=list(amatrix$technical_rep_number), mean)

nrow(new_table)
```

> ```
> 24
> ```

In `dplyr` we can use `group_by` and `summarize`:

```
new_table <- amatrix %>% 
              group_by(technical_rep_number) %>% 
              summarize(mean1 = mean(V1)) # etc
```

You can also take the means of all of the columns at once [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23768346/dplyr-colsums-on-sub-grouped-group-by-data-frames-elegantly):

```
new_table <- amatrix %>% 
              group_by(technical_rep_number) %>% 
              summarise_each(funs(mean))
```

Note that `summarise_each()` has been deprecated however, so I recommend `summarize_all()`:

```
new_table <- amatrix %>% 
              group_by(technical_rep_number) %>% 
              summarize_all(funs(mean))
```

Comment: This solved the problem in no time at all. Thanks for not only the speedy response, but also for the detailed explanation so I know what to do for similar issues next time.

Comment: @AlexCharles Happy to help, Alex. Cheers! Oh btw you can let future readers know this is the solution by clicking the green checkmark, if you are comfortable with that. :)